# How to use Alfresco with custom domain?

Tags: dns, alfresco

I've installed Alfresco CE in a Windows 7 machine (which is not ideal, but I have to deal with it). I can access my Alfresco share from inside the network:

```
192.168.2.252:8080/share
```

As far as I know, I can access it from outside the network using a dns service like `no-ip.org`, which gives me something like:

```
example.no-ip.org:8080/share
```

What I'm trying to do is to get something like:

```
mycustomdomain.com/share/ (removing the /share/ would be great too)
```

I've been reading a lot, but I'm not sure what to do. I read something about setting up DNS on my machine, but I don't know how to point the domain to the Alfresco share. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Ip which you have shared is internal IP.You need to have one external IP.Which can be accessed outside network.

Below file will help you in URL redirection.If you want to remove share , you may also do that by configuration in below file.

```
tomcat\webapps\share\WEB-INF\urlrewrite.xml
```

Comment: Sorry, but I've also share the external IP: no-ip.org does the job. That doesn't answer my question, which is how to point a domain to my Alfresco installation.

I tried adding an A record on my DNS setup pointing to my fixed external IP, but it won't work :-/ Thanks